# How do I let the computer go first in a simple game?

Tags: c#

So I created a simple game for an assignment for class. Where there is total of 21 chips and the player and computer can pick between 1-3 chips per turn and whoever reaches zero first wins. But I also have to randomly choose who goes first when the game starts. But I'm having difficulty writing the code so the computer can go first.

Can somebody please help me. If a number between 1-3 is randomly selected then player goes first. If 4 or 5 number randomly selected then the computer goes first.

```cs
    int chips = 21, user, computer;
    int pickPlayer;

    Random rn = new Random();

    pickPlayer = rn.Next(1, 5);

    if (pickPlayer == 1 || pickPlayer == 2 || pickPlayer == 3)
    {
        //Player goes First
        while (chips > 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("There are {0} Chips Choose Either 1,2,3 or 4 chips", chips);

            user = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            chips = chips - user;

            Random rnd = new Random();

            if (chips <= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You Lose");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            else
            {
                computer = rnd.Next(1, 4);

                Console.WriteLine("Computer picks {0} chips", computer);

                chips = chips - computer;

                if (chips <= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("You Win");
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Computer goes first
    }
}
```

Comment: Fundamentally, you need to abstract out the code for a computer taking a move and for the player taking a move. Then you should be able to greatly simplify your code and make it much easier to have either player start. Ideally you might think about having `Player` classes including a `HumanPlayer` and a `ComputerPlayer` both with a `TakeTurn` method, or something similar.

Comment: I agree with extracting these methods like a player-move and a computer-move but I feel like using classes for this might be a bit overkill don't you think?

Comment: @Joelius - not really, no. Especially as a learning experience.

Comment: @MattBurland Fair enough, learning experience always fits for things like this :)

Comment: FYI, the upperbound in `Random.Next(1, 5)` is ***exclusive***, which means you're only picking a number from `1` to `4`.

Answer (score 1):

Please, a simple solution using the "userTurn" flag.

```
int chips = 21, user, computer;

Random rn = new Random();
int pickPlayer = rn.Next(1, 5);

bool userTurn = pickPlayer == 1 || pickPlayer == 2 || pickPlayer == 3;

while (chips > 0)
{
    if (userTurn)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("There are {0} Chips Choose Either 1,2,3 or 4 chips", chips);

        user = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        chips = chips - user;

        if (chips <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You Lose");
            break;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        computer = rn.Next(1, 4);

        Console.WriteLine("Computer picks {0} chips", computer);

        chips = chips - computer;

        if (chips <= 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You Win");
            break;
        }
    }
    userTurn = !userTurn;
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it would be to create a class to represent a user, and then put an instance of this class (with the `Name` "Computer") along with another instance (given a `Name` by the user) into a `List<User>`. Then, we can determine who goes next by choosing an index of either `0` or `1` in our loop.

We can also give the class the ability to `PlayTurn`, a method that takes in a number of chips as an argument, and returns a number of chips after asking the user how many they want to take (or by taking a random amount if it's a computer player):

```
class Player
{
    private static readonly Random Random = new Random();
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsComputer { get; set; }

    public int PlayTurn(int chipsRemaining)
    {
        var maxToTake = Math.Min(4, chipsRemaining);

        var chipsTaken = IsComputer
            ? Random.Next(maxToTake) + 1
            : Program.GetIntFromUser(
                $"There are {chipsRemaining} chips remaining. " +
                $"Enter the number to take (1 - {maxToTake}): ",
                x => x > 0 && x <= maxToTake);

        if (IsComputer) Console.WriteLine($"Computer takes {chipsTaken} chips");

        return chipsRemaining - chipsTaken;
    }
}
```

Note that the `GetIntFromUser` method is a custom method that gets an integer from the user, and which allows a validation method to be passed in order to force them to enter a valid number, but you could use your own way of getting an `int` from them. The code for that method is in the next block.

Now, with the class above, we can write our program in just a few lines:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var rnd = new Random();
        var chips = 21;

        var players = new List<Player>
        {
            new Player {Name = "Computer", IsComputer = true},
            new Player {Name = GetStringFromUser("Please enter your name: ")}
        };

        // Decide who goes first by choosing a number from 1 - 5. 
        // If it's less than 4, the user goes first
        var nextPlayer = rnd.Next(1, 6) < 4 ? 1 : 0;
        var previousPlayer = nextPlayer;

        while (chips > 0)
        {
            chips = players[nextPlayer].PlayTurn(chips);
            previousPlayer = nextPlayer;

            // Here we choose the next player simply 
            // by changing `1` to `0` (or `0` to `1`)
            nextPlayer = nextPlayer == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        }

        Console.WriteLine(players[previousPlayer].IsComputer
            ? "Congratulations, you won!"
            : "Sorry, you lost. Better luck next time!");

        GetKeyFromUser("\n\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
    }

    // These are helper methods I use to get input from the user
    private static string GetStringFromUser(string prompt)
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
        return Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt, Func<int, bool> validator = null)
    {
        int result;
        var cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;

        do
        {
            ClearSpecificLineAndWrite(cursorTop, prompt);
        } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) ||
                    !(validator?.Invoke(result) ?? true));

        return result;
    }
}
```

**Sample Output with User going first**

[image]

**Sample Output with Computer going first**

[image]